# How does scandir() provided by the dirent library differ from python's os.scandir()?

Tags: yield, scandir, dirent.h

I want to know whether or not yielding is involved for dirent's scandir() method.

I went through documentation of os.scandir() and came across this statement -
It yields lightweight DirEntry objects that include file type and stat information along with the name.
I am trying to understand what happens in case of dirent's scandir().Does it return after fetching all entries or yield after each entry/set of entries?